# Monitoring a log file until it is complete

Tags: bash, shell, logfile

I am a high school student attempting to write a script in bash that will submit jobs using the "qsub" command on a supercomputer utilizing a different number of cores. This script will then take the data on the number of cores and the time it took for the supercomputer to complete the simulation from each of the generated log files, called "log.lammps", and store this data in a separate file.

Because it will take each log file a different amount of time to be completely generated, I followed the steps from
https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found
to have my script proceed when the last line of the log file with the string "Total wall time: " was generated.

Currently, I am using the following code in a loop so that this can be run for all the specified number of cores:

```sh
( tail -f -n0 log.lammps & ) | grep -q "Total wall time:"
```

However, running the script with this piece of code resulted in the log.lammps file being truncated and the script not completing even when the log.lammps file was completely generated.

Is there any other method for my script to only proceed when the submitted job is completed?

Comment: So you want `tail -F -n0` ? What is that `(  ...  & )` doing there? I think you can remove `(` `)` `&`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is touch a marker file once you're complete, and wait for that:

```
#start process:
rm -f finished.txt;
( sleep 3 ; echo "scriptdone" > log.lammps ; true ) && touch finished.txt &

# wait for the above to complete
while [ ! -e finished.txt ]; do
   sleep 1;
done

echo safe to process log.lammps now...
```

You could also use `inotifywait`, or a `flock` if you want to avoid busy waiting.

EDIT:

to handle the case where one of the first commands might fail, grouped first commands, and then added `true` to the end such that the group always returns true, and then did `&& touch finished.txt`.    This way finished.txt gets modified even if one of the first commands fails, and the loop below does not wait forever.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I just tried this but I found that my script would continue without recognizing that the log.lammps file was fully generated. Does this have to do with the value 3 right after sleep in the third line? Please clarify and let me know. Thank you!

Comment: The line starting with `sleep 3` ends with an `&`, which means the whole line (including the sleep) is run in the background.    Bash starts the new shell to run the commands, and immediately starts executing the next line (The `while` statement).   The `while` loop waits for the file `finished.txt` to exist.   (Because this file is `rm`'d at the beginning of the script, and is only recreated at the end of the background task, this busy loop will only exit once the background task has completed).

Comment: Just a note, the use `&&` in bash tells the loop to run the next command only if the first command completes sucesfully.   If the `sleep 3` fails for example, then the next command would never run, and `finished.txt` would never get written to.   In this case, the while loop below would never exit.

Comment: If your loop exists right away, you either have not removed finished.txt at the top, or your background task spawns yet another background task, which writes to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach

```
# run tail -f in background
(tail -f -n0 log.lammps | grep -q "Total wall time:")  > out 2>&1 &

# process id of tail command
tailpid=$!

# wait for some time or till the out file hqave data
sleep 10

# now kill the tail process
kill $tailpid
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this approach but got the following result: `awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file 'log.lammps' for reading (No such file or directory)
script.sh: line 39:  9774 Terminated              ( tail -f -n0 log.lammps | grep -q "Total wall time:" ) > out 2>&1`. I then checked the log.lammps file itself to see if any data was contained inside, but found it to be empty. I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me out. Thank you.

Comment: form the error that you get it seems that the file does not exist on the system

Comment: Could this be due to the fact that the file needs some time to be generated? My goal for this part of my script is to have the script continue once it has recognized that the contents of the file have been completely generated.

Comment: yes it could be , maybe you need to make sure that the file is created first

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do this sort of thing with:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/notify-when-up2.html
and
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/age/trunk/

So something like:

```
notify-when-up2 --greater-than-or-equal-to 0 'age /etc/passwd' 10
```

This doesn't look for a specific pattern in your file - it looks for when the file stops changing for a 10 seconds.  You can look for a pattern by replacing the age with a grep:

```
notify-when-up2 --true-command 'grep root /etc/passwd'
```

notify-when-up2 can do things like e-mail you, give a popup, or page you when a state changes.  It's not a pretty approach in some cases, compared to using wait or whatever, but I find myself using a several times a day.

HTH.